# Confirmation Message

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

If a user checks the `Checkbox`, how do I code to show `MessageBox.Show("..."`, with `YesNoCancel` buttons in the message box, and when a user clicks no, another `MessageBox.Show` pops up?

My code is this so far and it will not work:

```
private void lipsCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lipsCheckBox.Checked = MessageBox.Show("...?",
            "Want something else?",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBox.Show("...?",
            "Yea, Burt's bees?",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBox.Show("...??",
            "Hell yea LipxMedx?",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel),
            MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make a basic if statement?  This can't compile... I don't even understand what you pasted here.  It makes no sense, even from a pseudo-code point of view.

Comment: Show the first message box and `if (they clicked no)` show the other one.

Comment: In other words, how do I make my if statement to be processed, as if a user clicks my CheckBox, and then a MessageBox will appear to ask me a question, and that MessageBox should have YesNoCancel buttons, and if a user clicks no, another MessageBox should appear asking another question, and same format, (YesNoCancel) buttons, and if a user clicks no there, there should be another MessageBox asking another question. But if a user clicks yes before the second question (First question), then of course, the second would wouldn't show.

Answer (score 19):

You must know about the [`MessageBox Dialog`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show)

```
if (checkBox1.Checked && (MessageBox.Show("Yes or no", "The Title", 
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, 
    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes))
{
    //TODO: Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Do something like this:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{

     DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Message.", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

You should be able to use this snippet to do the rest of what you need.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it as follows:

```
private void lipsCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lipsCheckBox.Checked)
    {     
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("...?", "Want something else?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if(dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //
        }
        else if(dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```